# How to install prerequisites for minidlna (readymedia) on raspberry with Stretch?

Tags: debian, raspbian

I just updated my Raspberry installation from jessie to stretch and I wanted to install the latest minidlna version 1.2.1 from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/minidlna/files/minidlna/1.2.1/).

The main reason for this is the new option **-r** which softly rescans the media without erasing the whole index.

The README shows that I need **libexif, libjpeg, libid3tag, libFLAC, libvorbis, libsqlite3, libavformat** but I am not able to install those because the packages are not found.

I can install minidlna version 1.1.6 via apt-get.

Because version 1.2.1 is already several years old I was wondering why it is not part of stretch and if I can use for example **libexif-dev** instead of **libexif**.

EDIT: I tried the answer and got the same problem upon **make**. To be able to make successfully a package called `gettext`has to be installed before `./configure`.

Comment: No, this is normal. `minidlna` is installed to run as a service, not a standalone program. So if you really want this, you can add `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin/"` to your `~/.profile`, but that isn't really needed. If you already have it in `/etc/profile`, then it's being overwritten by something in your local config files (`~/.profile`, ~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: Thanks, please keep your comment here because this behaviour is different to version 1.1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the packages you mention should be found, they just might have slightly different names. The README file of `minildna` just lists the libraries it needs. It has no way of knowing what operating system you are using and what those libraries will be packaged as on your system. So the trick is to just use `apt-cache search` or even `apt install libexif` and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to see the available completions. In most cases, you should see a package whose name starts with what you're looking for and is followed by a number (the version, kinda).

Now, since what you want is to be able to compile something, that usually means you want the `foo-dev` package, not just the `foo` one. This is what I used on my system (I am not sure all of these were actually needed, but most were):

```
sudo apt install libexif12 libjpeg9 libid3tag0 libflac8 libvorbis0a libsqlite3-0 \
                 libavformat57 libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libjpeg9-dev libsqlite3-dev \
                 libexif-dev libid3tag0-dev libogg-dev libvorbis-dev libflac-dev \
                 gettext
```

Actually, I am 90% sure that all you really need is to install the dev packages, those should bring in the rest. So first just try:

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libjpeg9-dev libsqlite3-dev \
                 libexif-dev libid3tag0-dev libogg-dev libvorbis-dev libflac-dev \
                 gettext
```

After running the command above on my Raspbian, I could run `./configure` on the minildna package with no problem.

Comment: I fixed that. Missing package was `gettext`. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben what did you fix? The `make` error I mention? Something else? Installing `gettext` made no difference for me.

Comment: Installing gettext and then ./configure and make did fix the problem you mentioned (I had the exact same one). V1.2.1 is now running on my system. I edited my question accordingly, because I PATH is not working yet and I had a strange output from `make install`.

Comment: @Ben thanks! Re-running configure after installing gettext did indeed fix it. I don't see anything strange in your `make install` (but it might help t run it again with `LC_ALL=C make install` so we can see output in English). If it worked, it worked!

Comment: What I mean is the part starting with `if`, `else` and ending with `fi`. It is a code phrase. So I don't understand why this code phrase is printed instead of beeing used in the code.

Comment: @Ben it's both printed _and_ used probably. Don't worry about it, I've seen things like that quite often.

Comment: Thanks! Please consider pointing out `gettext` more obiously because I had the list of dependencies from the minidlna project and `gettext` is missing there.

Comment: I don't really see how to make it more obvious. There's nothing special about it, just one of the packages you need to install. And since it's the last one, all one ona  single line, that's the most obvious one :)